# VHDL Error: TwosCompliment.vhd(16): near "process": expecting "BEGIN"

Tags: vhdl

I've been trying to write a 2's complement converter for a class, but I keep running into the error mentioned above. I'm new to using conditional statements so it very well could be a newbie error. This is what I have written so far:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity converter is
Port ( 
    sign_mag : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) ;
    output : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end converter;

architecture arch of converter is

signal tmp_out : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal not_mag : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

process(sign_mag) is 
begin
    if sign_mag(3) = '0' then tmp_out <= sign_mag;
    else 
        not_mag(3) <= sign_mag(3);
        not_mag(2) <= not sign_mag(2);
        not_mag(1) <= not sign_mag(1);
        not_mag(0) <= not sign_mag(0);
        tmp_out <= not_mag + 0001;  
    end if;
end process;
--output <= not tmp_out;
output <= tmp_out;

end arch;
```

All it is supposed to do is check if the most significant bit is '1' or '0'. If '0', output will equal input. If '1', output will be equal to the sign bit and the inverse of the magnitude bits, plus "0001".

Comment: An *if* statement is a sequential statement. It can only *survive* in a sequential environment like a subprogram (function, procedure) or process. The region after `begin` in your architecture accepts only concurrent statements. In conclusion: You need to embed your statement in a process statement.

Comment: You should not use non-IEEE packages like `std_logic_unsigned`. Use `numeric_std` instead. By using the latter package, no manual 2s complement conversion is required. Just use the appropriate types (and pre-defined conversion functions) in VHDL.

Comment: @Paebbels: Shouldn't this be an answer rather than comments?

Comment: @DLnd It's only adding 2 lines to the example so no overwhelming good answer :). Problem is more or less that the complete 2s complement conversion algorithm is wrong ... E.g. the port clause is incomplete.

Comment: I've added "process(sign_mag) is" above begin, and "end process" after the end if. Now i have an error saying "Error: TwosCompliment.vhd(16): near "process": expecting "BEGIN" "

Comment: I got it working. I was missing another begin statement before the process, and also missing the line use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all; at the top.

Comment: Your algorithm is still incorrect. The 2s complement is about encoding a sign (boolean value or bit) into an absolute number to represent negative numbers. In your case you are extracting the absolute number from a 2s complement number. In that process also the sign information is extracted. This means, your entity needs a second output that returns this information. Otherwise your entity is not the reverse operation of the insertion operation, that merges an absolute number with a sign information to a 2s complement number.

Comment: Another problem is that you need to invert all bits before you increment the number if the number is negative. You are currently trying to calculate the absolute value of a given number. There for you can also use the `abs` operator in VHDL. Moreover, your design creates latches, because you falsely use object `not_mag` of object class *signal* instead of class *variable*. The update of `not_mag` is delayed by one process evaluation cycle. The next problem is that your simulation model of that process differs from the synthesized model. (A `begin` before `process` is still missing in your code

Comment: No, you are not missing the line `use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;`. That package is not part of the standard and shouldn't be used. Learn to use `numeric_std`.

Answer (score 0):

Although your implementation is incorrect, the main question is about the syntax of VHDL.

VHDL is described in an IEEE-standard: IEEE std 1076-2008. Unless you have a IEEE connection, you will have to pay to be able to read this standard. Luckily, there are many VHDL resources online, e.g.:

- [VHDL tutorial: learn by example](http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/labs/tutorial/)
- [VHDL Tutorial - Introduction to VHDL for beginners](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tutorials/tutorial-introduction-to-vhdl-for-beginners.html)
- [VHDL Reference Guide](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/)
- Etc.

**Edit: note not all these guides are up-to-date with the latest version of the standard!!**

Basically, VHDL `entity`, `architecture`, `block`, `process`, `generate`, etc. declarations have a *declarative* part and a *statement* part. The statement part should always be preceded by the `begin` keyword (*even* if there is no declarative part). E.g.

```
architecture behavior of test_bench is
    -- declarative part, e.g.
    signal foo : bit;
begin
    -- statement part, e.g.
    foo <= '0';
end architecture;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your *unasked* question is that you have a syntax error due to a missing `begin` keyword after the architecture declarative area.

```
architecture arch of converter is

signal tmp_out : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal not_mag : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin -------<<<<< You are missing this
process(sign_mag) is 
begin
.
.
.
```

P.S.: I think you are being dinged by other readers for not asking a question.